# How to test mysql insert method

Tags: mysql, go, testing, go-sqlmock

I'm setting up `testing` in Go. I use `go-sqlmock` to test `mysql` connection. Now I try to test mysql `insert` logic. But the error occurs.
I want to know how to resolve this error.

```
server side: golang
db: mysql
web framework: gin
```

dao.go

```golang
func PostDao(db *sql.DB, article util.Article, uu string) {
    ins, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO articles(uuid, title,content) VALUES(?,?,?)")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ins.Exec(uu, article.TITLE, article.CONTENT)
}
```

dao_test.go

```golang
func TestPostArticleDao(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("an error '%s' was not expected when opening a stub database connection", err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    mock.ExpectExec("^INSERT INTO articles*").
        WithArgs("bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c", "test", "test").
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))

    article := util.Article{
        ID:      1,
        TITLE:   "test",
        CONTENT: "test",
    }

    PostDao(db, article, "bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c")

    if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("there were unfulfilled expections: %s", err)
    }
}
```

I expect `go test -v` runs without error.
But the actual is not.
Here is the error.

```
=== RUN   TestPostArticleDao
2019/08/31 00:08:11 call to Prepare statement with query 'INSERT INTO articles(uuid, title,content) VALUES(?,?,?)', was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedExec => expecting Exec or ExecContext which:
  - matches sql: 'INSERT INTO articles(uuid, title,content) VALUES(?,?,?)'
  - is with arguments:
    0 - bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c
    1 - test
    2 - test
  - should return Result having:
      LastInsertId: 1
      RowsAffected: 1
exit status 1
FAIL    article/api/dao 0.022s
```

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. It expected an Exec, but got a Pepare. What part do you need help with ?

Comment: @Flimzy I want to resolve this error and make this test success.

Comment: Obviously you want to fix it. The question is what help do you need beyond reading the error message?

Answer (score 2):

As @Flimzy suggested, it needs to set `ExpectPrepare` first.
So I changed `dao_test.go` in this way:

```golang
    prep := mock.ExpectPrepare("^INSERT INTO articles*")

    prep.ExpectExec().
        WithArgs("bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c", "test", "test").
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked without asterix:

```
mock.ExpectExec("INSERT INTO `mytable`").WithArgs(mockdbutils.AnyTime{}, mockdbutils.AnyTime{}, nil, 4455,false).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(int64(4455), 1))
    mock.ExpectCommit()
```